# Matplotlib: Uneven grid of images on y axis scale

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I would like to plot an array of images (molecular orbitals) on a y scale unevenly, according to their y value (energy), with matplotlib.

I know a grid of images can be done with subplots, but this is limited to evenly spaced images, which is not what I want. Moreover, I want a single y scale to represent the values associated to each image.

Comment: The matplotlib's class hierarchy goes as follows Figure(entire image that you see when plt.show()) that contains many Axes objects(represent individual subplots) that contain a bunch of assorted Artist subclasses. While matplotlib provides a lot of ways to create gridlocked Axes objects, you can absolutely create Axes of arbitrary shape and position by using `fig=plt.figure(); ax=figure.add_axes(rectangle)`. Check out matplotlib's Figure class doccumentation: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure

Comment: Thank you, that is precisely the aim of my question: how to do this? It is not clear to me how to have a single y axis for many subplots and plotting images (imshow) at specific y positions.

Comment: You can call `ax.imshow` (or `ax.pcolormesh`) as many times as you want on the same axes, `ax`, and specify the `extent` kwarg: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html

Comment: A second approach is to use inset axes to place your images in their own axes if that is more convenient: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.inset_axes.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `OffsetImage` placed inside an `AnnotationBbox` to position your image anywhere you like.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import (OffsetImage, AnnotationBbox)

def image(x, y, ax, fname, zoom=0.5):
    """Place image from file `fname` into axes `ax` at position `x,y`."""
    ar = plt.imread(fname)
    im = OffsetImage(ar, zoom=zoom)
    im.image.axes = ax

    ab = AnnotationBbox(im, (x,y), xycoords='data')
    ax.add_artist(ab)


path = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/"
exts = ["1/15/Hydrogen_eigenstate_n1_l0_m0_wedgecut.png/30px-Hydrogen_eigenstate_n1_l0_m0_wedgecut.png",
        "c/c6/Hydrogen_eigenstate_n2_l1_m0.png/50px-Hydrogen_eigenstate_n2_l1_m0.png",
        "2/21/Hydrogen_eigenstate_n3_l1_m0.png/70px-Hydrogen_eigenstate_n3_l1_m0.png",
        "f/f5/Hydrogen_eigenstate_n3_l1_m-1.png/70px-Hydrogen_eigenstate_n3_l1_m-1.png",
        "6/6a/Hydrogen_eigenstate_n3_l2_m1.png/70px-Hydrogen_eigenstate_n3_l2_m1.png"]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axis([-1,5,-1,5])
for i, p in enumerate(exts):
    image(i, i, ax, path+p)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! There is a problem though: it seems that when I zoom down the images, the quality is highly affected (high-resolution images become pixelized). Do you know how to tackle this problem?

Comment: Downsampling images reduces their quality. Matplotlib renderers do not provide means to smoothen downsampled images. You may achieve better results by downsampling the images beforehand (e.g. via a Lanczos filter) and use `zoom=1`.